# optimal sequential wagering strategy to reach a high target payoff in minimal amount of time

Tags: probability

Suppose we repeatedly play a game where we wager a certain amount $N_i$ in round $i$ and then we either receive double our wager with probability $p$ or lose the wager with probability $1 - p$. Suppose further we start with a given amount $S$ and we wish to eventually obtain a target amount of $T$. Further assume that if our current amount ever goes below $S$, we are replenished to $S$ again. We may as well assume $S = 1$.

The goal is to minimize the expected time (number of rounds) to reach amount $T$. Clearly if $p = 1$ then the best strategy is to wager the maximum amount (our entire current holdings) each round. Also if $p \simeq 0$ it seems that probably wagering the maximum amount each round is the best strategy, because the law of large numbers would say that our current holdings are almost guaranteed to go down in the long run if we wager much lesser amounts.

What about $p$ closer to $1/2$? Is it still optimal to bet the maximum amount each round? Or is it better to wager lesser amounts so that the law of large numbers starts to take over (i.e. if $p > 1/2$)?

The reason I'm interested in this problem is that I'm playing on a play money poker site where you play No Limit Texas Hold'em, and my philosophy is to play until I either double my entry stakes or lose it all, and then reevaluate what my entry stakes should be. So this is a pretty close approximation to my situation. I believe that for me, $p \simeq 0.75$ or so, and I'd like to know how often and to what to change the stakes I'm playing so that I build a big bankroll quickly.

I believe the that as long as $T \gg S$, the optimal strategy will always be to wager a fixed fraction $\alpha(p)$ of our current holdings, where the fraction $\alpha$ depends on $p$. Even if we just solve for $\alpha(p)$ in the case $T/S \to \infty$, that would still be interesting because in theory there is no upper bound on how much I want to profit =)

Comment: Is there a real strategy in a game like this? Whether you bet the max amount, or many small amounts, or anywhere in between... in the long run isn't it all the same. I guess I could make a simulation for billions of games that shows this.

Comment: @JLee I'd be surprised if that's true because as $p \to 1$ it certainly will take longer than necessary if you keep wagering very small amounts, rather than larger amounts.

Comment: Having S replenished automatically is every gambler's dream.

Comment: @JLee Sure, which is why I also stipulated that we may charge a certain number of rounds if we go below $S$. This is inspired by a poker website where you get $S=1000$ and then 3 times per hour you can get replenished to $S = 1000$ but only 3 times per hour.

Comment: If this question is not answered in the next 5 hours, I will create a simulation, because my intuition is just not definitive enough. Intuitively, it seems to me that if you are only concerned with minimizing the time to reach an amount, then maximize every bet.

Comment: @JLee I wouldn't be surprised if the optimal strategy is to always wager the maximum amount. I _would_ be surprised if the optimal strategy doesn't matter as far as wagering a little or wagering a lot.

Comment: yeah, my first comment missed the point. from an expected value perspective, it wouldn't matter, but for your specific concern, it probably does

Comment: In a comment, you say that there can be a charge of a certain number of rounds for going below $S$ and getting replenished, but I don't see this in the question. Do you want to include this or not?

Comment: The optimal strategy at $x$ is to bet the maximum possible ($x$), or the amount required to take you exactly to the goal ($T-x$), whichever is smaller.

Answer (score 1):

I created a simulation in Excel for Win % = 50%. I set S=100 and T=1000.

Each test (line) ran 10 million games.

Here are the results:

> ```
> % Wagered Avg # Rounds per Game
> 100%      29.999
> 90%       29.999
> 80%       29.997
> 70%       52.396
> 60%       52.023
> 50%       84.557
> 40%       115.48
> 30%       199.759
> 20%       memory overflow
> ```

---

EDIT: 3-13-2015:
I recreated the sim(ulation) using C#, and ran lots of numbers for you, changing just the Win Percent and the Percent Wagered.

[image]

Each cell in the table below is the result of 10 million full games played, and the number of rounds it required (on average) to reach \$1000, when starting from \$100.

[image]

Lastly, if you are interested in the values when the Win % is less than 50, or the % Wagered is less than 45, then let me know, and I will run the sim for those values as well. I just didn't want to take all that time to run them if you don't see the value of the simulation results, or if it's not helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for this, it confirms that the optimal strategy seems to be wagering the maximum amount when $p = 1/2$. However when $p > 1/2$ but $p$ is not close to $1$, that's when I start to wonder. I'm pretty sure the optimal strategy is to always wager the maximum amount when $p \leq 1/2$. But if $p > 1/2$, say $p = 3/4$ then I'm not sure.

Comment: I'd like to send you the sim, assuming you have Microsoft Excel. You can play around with the numbers all you want. What is the best way to send you a message on here outside of these comments?

Comment: I added more numbers for you, for when p>1/2. It might be best just to send you the C# sim and let you move the number around and run different simulations to see how things distribute.